# AES encryption for openwrt distribution

Tags: encryption, openwrt

I'm using openwrt distribution and I want to encrypt a file using AES. How can I do that quickly and easily, and how can I - or someone else -decrypt it again?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Gnupg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) or [P7zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)). Both are available as packages on OpenWRT.

With Gnupg, you can either use [public-key encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) (you encrypt with one or more public keys and someone with the corresponding private key can decrypt) (`gpg -e`), or encryption with a key that's derived from a password (`gpg -c`). GnuPG doesn't actually use AES by default, but [that's irrelevant](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2009/july/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing-it-wrong/).

With p7zip, run `7z -mem=AES128 -p archive.zip myfile`. Beware that the password will end up in your shell history and can be seen by other users on the same machine if they run `ps` while the `7z` process is running. Note that if you forget the `-p` option, `7z` produces a non-encrypted archive.

Do not use the `zip` command or the `ZipCrypto` method of p7zip. It produces encrypted zip files with an ancient, broken encryption algorithm.

Do not use the `openssl` command. Although it can use AES-CBC (in addition to a number of insecure algorithms such as DES-* or *-ECB), the way it generates a key from a password is broken (even if you salt it, which is not the case by default, it's too slow, so it's easy to brute force).